# How to find webmail server address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, webmail

My webmail is associated with local ip address. To configure it with gmail, I need to find the server name. Is there a way to find server name?

Comment: Exactly what URL do you type into your web-browser to reach your webmail page?

Comment: the local ip address. because my pc is in the same network.

Comment: You need to have the webserver's public (or routable) address to connect it to GMail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **My webmail is associated with local ip address**

When people write "local IP address" they usually mean one of two things:

- The IP-address of the main network interface of a personal computer.
- The IP-address of a server (a different computer) on the local network.

It is unusual to run a mail service on a personal desktop or notebook computer.
If you have a separate mail-server, whoever set that up will know it's name.

> **To configure it with gmail, I need to find the server name.**

That would be unusual. Usually you can use a *public* IP-address anywhere you can use a name (specifically a DNS fully qualified hostname).

> **Is there a way to find server name?**

You can try a reverse-DNS lookup.

```
C:\>nslookup 10.0.0.16
Server:  myLocalNatRouter
Address:  10.0.0.252

Name:    myLocalMailServer
Address:  10.0.0.16
```

---

If the webmail server is behind a NAT router or firewall, you will need for port-forwarding to be configured. Once you (or a helper) understand that, you'll know what name to give gmail.